# How do I use the android media services to return that media to my activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, mediastore

I'm interested in capturing media to use in my activity in two ways:

1) capturing immediately from the supplied app. (like [Using the camera activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314958/using-the-camera-activity-in-android))

> Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
>         this.startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);

2) browse a picture/video/audio gallery and pick from the list.

I notice I can call up for the photo gallery

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, target); 
>
> startActivity(intent);

But how about for video only?  audio only?  How will I get the URI from any of them?

Answer (score 0):

a FEW problems, you need to do startActivityForResult..

But just take a look at this post, its already been done by lots of people.

[Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent)