# Camera in Android

Tags: android, camera

I want to use camera facility in android application.

I want to capture image on click of button control can any one suggest me the best example of it.

Comment: please search this site for "android camera capture"

Answer (score 6):

Try android dev's site: [Camera access in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) also read this article: [Using android camera](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-android-application-development-isbn-978-0-470-34471-2/72528-article-using-android-camera.html)

And for more look at related section of this question.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are a few Q&A here to get started:

[Using the camera activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314958/using-the-camera-activity-in-android)

[Use camera flashlight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android)

[Android camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)

[How do I save data from Camera to disk using MediaStore on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649057/how-do-i-save-data-from-camera-to-disk-using-mediastore-on-android)

And some tutorials out there:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/

http://2008.hfoss.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_Camera_Application

http://www.androidph.com/2008/11/camera-capture.html

http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/CameraTutorial

Comment: please guide regarding android.hardware.Camera2 example after updating sdk not able to resolve some classes like Listner

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(id);
 button.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener()
            {
         public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 730);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1115);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 730);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 1115);
                intent.setAction("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
           startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
        @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA : if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            { 
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
                values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "test");
                values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "test Image taken");
                values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selectedimage)).setImageBitmap(photo);
                OutputStream outstream;
                try {
                        outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, outstream);
                        outstream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
                catch (IOException e){}
            }
            break;
```

EDIT: its perfect and working.just try it and provide me feedback if u like it.

Answer (score 2):

Please Check this answer :

```
public class ImageUploading extends Activity 
{   
    Uri imageUri = null;
    ImageButton btnSubmit   ;
    public void onCreate(Bundle onsavedInstantState)
    {
        super.onCreate(onsavedInstantState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile);
        btnSubmit               = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);       
        btnSubmit.setClickable(true);       
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"my_photo.png");
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);               
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,0);             
            }
        });
    }   
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent imageIntent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, imageIntent);
        try
        {
            if(RequestCode == 0)
            {
                if(ResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
                    ContentResolver objContentResolver = getContentResolver();
                    Bitmap imgBitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(objContentResolver, imageUri);
                    Drawable imgDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(imgBitmap);
                    btnSubmit.setBackgroundDrawable(imgDrawable);
                }
            }           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

It will capture image on button click, and set this image as background image for that button itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hy Check these all links .. i hope its useful for you.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-taking-photos-with-andorid-built-in-camera/

http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/

https://github.com/mistaguy/snapit/tree/master/src/com/mistaguy/snapit

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/

http://notes.hfoss.org/index.php/Tutorial:Camera_and_Gallery_Demo

http://www.anddev.org/take_picture_from_camera_emulator-t168.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, if it doesnt work I will give you the trunk link.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html