# Accessing camera using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

What i am trying to do is create a new folder and save the image captured by camera in that folder.I am trying to achieve it using following snipet:

```
public class DocsAdd extends Activity
{   
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri outputFileUri;
    Bitmap thumbnail;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);        
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        File filename;
        try 
        {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String fileName = "img" + currentTime+".jpg";
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();             
            filename = new File(path + "/AutoistDiary/"+ fileName);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);            
            out.flush();
            out.close();     
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(), filename.getName());

          outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(filename);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri imageUri = null;            
            if (data!=null) 
            {
                if (data.hasExtra("data")) 
                {
                    thumbnail = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                    Intent docsShow_intent=new Intent(this,DocsShow.class);
                    startActivity(docsShow_intent);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
            }

        }  
    }
}
```

but when i run it on Optimus1 it is not returning any result to my activity, came across a link [Camera on Android Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449414/camera-on-android-example) which states the same problem that i am facing currently so can help me with this. ?

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: Why dont u just give it a try @JeremyWest mostly yes it is working...!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is a bug on some devices causing the `Intend data` parameter in `onActivityResult` to be null when you use the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` flag in your intent for the camera. A workaround is to keep the `outputFileUri` variable global so that you can access it again in your `onActivityResult` method. Something like this:

```
Uri outputFileUri; //global variable

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File photo= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Autoist Diary"); 

if (! photo.exists())  
{  
    photo.mkdirs();  
    if (! photo.mkdirs())  
    {  
        Log.i("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");  
    }  
}  
puc_img=new File(photo,"Puc_Img.jpg");  
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri);  
StartActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);  

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
{  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    switch (requestCode)   
    {  
       case TAKE_PICTURE:  
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)   
           {                   
               if(data != null) { //if the intent data is not null, use it
                  puc_image = getImagePath(Uri.parse(data.toURI())); //update the image path accordingly
                  StoreImage(this,Uri.parse(data.toURI()),puc_img);
               }
               else { //Use the outputFileUri global variable
                  StoreImage(this,outputFileUri,puc_img);
               }
           }   
       break;
    }  
}  
public static void StoreImage(Context mContext, Uri imageLoc, File imageDir)  
{  
    Bitmap bm = null;  
    try   
    {  
        bm = Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageLoc);  
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageDir);  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);  
        bm.recycle();  
    }  
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)   
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    catch (IOException e)   
    {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    catch (Exception e)   
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
public String getImagePath(Uri uri) {
    String selectedImagePath;
    // 1:MEDIA GALLERY --- query from MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else {
        selectedImagePath = null;
    }

    if (selectedImagePath == null) {
        // 2:OI FILE Manager --- call method: uri.getPath()
        selectedImagePath = uri.getPath();
    }
    return selectedImagePath;
}
```

This workaroud has worked for me. Hope that helps.

Comment: giving error at      StoreImage(this,Uri.parse(outputFileUri),puc_img); Uri.parse() parses a string and not a Uri.so what i am supposed to pass to this method

Comment: @sankettt Sorry my fault. I have updated my answer. You already the correct `Uri` for the  `StoreImage` method.

Comment: The code is working properly but i am facing one strange issue..the file saved on the device i mentioned is 0kb.. what can be the issue with this. but at the same time when i tried on other device it is working properly. may be this is the bug of 2.2.. any help regarding this

Comment: @sankettt I have updated my answer. Hope this solves your problem. I think the problem was that the variable `puc_image` was not updated in `onActivityResult` when the `Intent data` was not null.

Comment: hey @angelo i have used some other code which is working fine for 2.3 but stores 0kb for 2.2 i am putting the code here for u to refer.!

Comment: @sankettt I dont think the problem is the version of the Adnroid but the diffferent devices. Every device has its own implementation for the camera, and some of them have the problem mentioned in your question. I am not sure the code you are using is absolutely correct. I think it only works in devices that do not have the `Intent data` null bug in `onActivityResult` method. I recommend you to make the appropriate modifications with the code snipet i posted.

Comment: ohk will check it. if any problem i would get back to u.

Comment: can u help me with another problem regarding animation i have a question that i have posted can you check it ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006157/animation-not-repeating-on-click-of-image#comment17648861_13006157

Comment: @sankettt I will gladly help you (if i can ofcourse) with your question but it seems that you already found a solution to your question:)

Comment: Can't believe this still isn't fixed, just got this error.