# Animation Not Repeating on Click of Image

Tags: android, android-animation

On Click of a `Textview` i am doing frame animation using following piece of code

```
imgclickanimation.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickframeanimation);
ribinclickanimation= (AnimationDrawable) imgclickanimation.getBackground();
```

and on Click of the `TextView` i am  starting the animation using 
`ribinclickanimation.start();`

`clickframeanimation` is the anim file.
and `ribinclickanimation` is the object of `AnimationDrawable`
It works properly for the first time when i click but when i click for the second time onwards  nothing happens can anyone suggest me any help.

**CODE: **

```
package com.example.tryfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    TextView imgclickanimation;
    AnimationDrawable ribinclickanimation;//,ribinanimation;
    int duration=200;
    ScrollView scroll;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgclickanimation= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imgclickanimation);



        imgclickanimation.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgclickanimation.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickframeanimation);
        ribinclickanimation= (AnimationDrawable) imgclickanimation.getBackground();
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        if(arg0.getId()==imgclickanimation.getId())
        {
            imgclickanimation.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickframeanimation);
            ribinclickanimation.start();

        }
    }
}
```

and my clickframeanimation.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ribin3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ribin4" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ribin3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: Why don't you post some more code for better understanding your problem.

Comment: I mean the code surrounding this, the listener on the textview, the activity etc. There could be something wrong with that.

Comment: ` public void onClick(View arg0) 
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(arg0.getId()==imgclickanimation.getId())
  {
   ribinclickanimation.start();
  }
 }
`
all i am doing is starting the animation. and if i set `android:oneshot` property="false" in the xml file it would start the animation again and again.
which i want on the click of textview

Comment: What is the animation that you are doing?

Comment: this code will load frame animation as for the xml file :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ribin3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ribin4" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ribin3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>`
hope this will help u understand a bit more

Comment: It would actually help if you could post the entire code as a part of the question itself (with formatting ofcourse). However just a wild guess trying insert this code inside onClickListener "imgclickanimation.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickframeanimation);".. May be that would work..

Comment: checked that thing but no use. no animation on the click of `TextView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the update code

```
package com.example.tryfinal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 TextView imgclickanimation;
    AnimationDrawable ribinclickanimation;//,ribinanimation;
    int duration=200;
    ScrollView scroll;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgclickanimation= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imgclickanimation);
        imgclickanimation.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgclickanimation.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickframeanimation);
        ribinclickanimation= (AnimationDrawable) imgclickanimation.getBackground();
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        ribinclickanimation.stop();
        if(arg0.getId()==imgclickanimation.getId())
        {
            imgclickanimation.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickframeanimation);//It will still work without this line. There is no need to set the resource again.

            ribinclickanimation.start();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the table layout u mentioned ?

Comment: hey can u help me with a similar issue.. this time its related to fling event.

Comment: Please post it as a separate question and I will try and answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008435/animating-on-the-fling-event.. here is the post