# frame-by-frame animation API compatibilty

Tags: android

I am using the following code to set Frmae-by-frame animation :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);



        final ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_image);
        back.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_animation);

        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) back.getBackground();

         // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
         frameAnimation.setExitFadeDuration(2000);
         frameAnimation.start();
}
```

However, the `setExitFadeDuration` only works after API level 11. Is there an alternative to the code that I used to make the animation compatible with API 7 onwards

Comment: check this it may help u ..though a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006157/animation-not-repeating-on-click-of-image. here i have started the frame animation on the click of image.

Comment: If I use your code, the images will change but there will not be any fade effect which is what I want to achieve.