# Xamarin Android Camera and Video

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera-intent

I can easily open the camera and take a picture in xamarin Android. but what if I want to open the camera intent and then choose to select whether I want to take the picture or video? right now I can find that I have to define "ActionImageCapture" / "ActionVideoCapture" before open the Intent.

Is there a way to do that? I tried to find in the internet but could not found a solution regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's still not possible to have one intent for two purposes.

So the solution offered in the Answer below should still be a valid workaround.

[Android Camera for Picture and Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140834/android-camera-for-picture-and-video)